# Is WAS activation over MSMQ a legend or what?

Tags: wcf, iis, msmq, was, netmsmqbinding

I'm working on my fourth or fifth implementation of a WCF service over MSQM with IIS/WAS activation. And I was never able to make it work properly. It's always the same story: my services are activated only if the IIS web site was interacted some other way (like servicing the service metadata page at /somewhere/myService.svc). Suddenly, if the only thing happening is sending messages into the queue, my services stop to process messages, and restart as soon as I visit the .svc page...

It's a so common pattern for me, that I also came to a common solution: scheduling a job (every few minutes) that runs a powershell script that access that page. Quite simple, but not very elegant. And, further more, unnecessary in theory.

This happened over different IIS versions (7.0  and 7.5), over various Win 2008 service packs and releases and with server in AD domains or workgroups. I think I've read every bits on the web about this, especially MSDN and microsofties blog, so binding configuration, MSMQ permissions, and all the other small details you can discover here and there are set up.

So the question: does anybody was successful with WAS over MSMQ?